# Android TextView Text Change Error

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-activity

I have an display layout with two item one of them is imageView and the other one is a TextView.I'm using this layout display many things but there is a problem.Problem is let's say I run an activity uses this layout this activity fills it and kill itself.Later if I call another Activity uses that Layout it changes image but text still same.I dont want to post all of the code but If you guys needed I can post it.

```
setContentView(R.layout.info_display_tablet);
    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    tx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    try {
        result = MethodInfoGetter.methodRequest("CTVIslemleriGetir", "", "");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    tx.setText("");
    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.cevre_temizlik);
    tx.setText(result.get(0).get(1).toString());
```

here is my first call let's asume and the second call's code is

```
public class BalikesirTarih extends Activity
{
ArrayList<ArrayList> result = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();
ImageView iv;
TextView tx;
Bitmap bmp = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.info_display_tablet);
    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    tx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    try {
        result = MethodInfoGetter.methodRequest("BalikesirTarihiGetir", "", "");
        Log.i("Balikesir tarihi log denemesi",result.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    new asTask().execute();
}

private class asTask extends AsyncTask<Void , Void ,Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("http://balikesir.bel.tr/Balikesir_Tarihi/Resim_b_1.jpg");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        tx.setText("");
        tx.setText(result.get(0).get(1).toString());
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}
}
```

Comment: You don't have to post all your code, but without the relevant bits, we won't be able to help you.

Comment: The text will be the default text in your `layout.xml` file every time you load it unless you save the value and specifically set it when you inflate the `layout`. I think you need to provide *some* code and/or a better explanation because this is confusing.

Comment: Here is my code that I call in program.

Comment: Have you checked in your `try/catch` to see if you are getting an exception or if `result` is being initialized to the expected value?

Comment: I look it returns different data but I cant change the text.

Comment: So are you saying you expect the changes to the text view from the first activity to still be there when the next activity inflates the same layout? Whenever you call `setContentView` it is going to inflate the layout directly from XML. Any changes from some other activity will have been lost if you didn't pass them to the new activity in an extra.

Comment: I want to chance leftover text from other activity.

Comment: You cannot use the text view to pass data from one activity to another. You will need to store it in an extra in the Intent you use to open the new activity, or store it in a singleton and retrieve it after you open the new activity.

Comment: I'm not trying to pass data.Ok let's ask this Can I use same layout over and over again If I can I think there is nothing wrong with my logic.

Comment: You can inflate the same layout over and over with `setContentView`, but every time you call `setContentView` it is inflating a new layout with all the default values that you specified in your XML. You cannot pass the same instance of the layout to be used in the next activity.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the text view to pass data from one activity to another.

One way to do it is with an extra. When you are opening the next activity you can do this:

```
   Intent intent = /*create intent for opening the next activity*/;
   intent.addExtra("textLabel", tx.getText());
   startActivity(intent); //or however you are opening next activity
```

Then in the next activity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.info_display_tablet);
    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    tx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    String passedTextLabel = getIntent.getExtra("textLabel","");
    tx.setText(passedTextLabel);
    ....

}
```

However, if your first activity is not the activity that opens the second activity, you might have an easier time storing the data in a singleton. So in your first activity, when you get the data:

```
tx.setText(result.get(0).get(1).toString());
MySingleton.instance().setTextLabel(result.get(0).get(1).toString());
```

And then in the next activity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.info_display_tablet);
    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    tx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    tx.setText(MySingleton.instance().getTextLabel());
    ....
```

Comment: I have different kind of data I don't want to pass anything I just want to change layout's text to new data every time.

Comment: Then it is still not clear what you want. From the code you posted, what is happening wrong that you did not expect?

Comment: Ok.I have one layout and first code I'm using it to display some stuff and activity kill itself when I'm press back button and later on I'm starting another Activity to display another data but I cannot delete old data so it's my problem.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just don't understand. From the code you posted I don't see how anything from the old finished activity would have any impact on your second activity.

Comment: Activiies are indipendent but layouts text doesn't chance after the first Activity.

Comment: Something must be going wrong in your `asTask` class. Try simplifying it, or adding some log messages to see what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

From what You are saying, and what I'm understanding, I think you are hardcoding text on your layout xml.
If you need to maintain some values for your textView then check out the preferences API, so you can store your last value and reset it once loaded thelayout on the activity.
If this is not what you want to do please be more specific (giving an example and showing us your layout xml)